# Excel Dax - average entries from table with only one date selected

Tags: excel, pivot, dax

I'm looking to make a pivot table that averages the last 3 data entries from a table (prior to the date i have selected) using the Dax functions. Below is my data table.

[image]

I'm currently using the following dax measure: **=CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table1[AHT]),TOPN(3,Table1,[AHT],ASC))**

This yields the answer I'm looking for, if all (or none) of my dates are selected in the pivot table:

[image]

However, when I select a date - it's just returning the value of the row. The value I would be looking for is 300 (average of the 18th, 17th, and 16th)

[image]

Any assistance would be much appreciated!!!!

Comment: And what should the resuit be if more than one date is selected in the slicer? Or is this disallowed? Also, is each date unique?

Comment: Also, what should the result be if you choose 1st December in your example?